# Progressive Measurability implies Measurability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The stochastic process X is called **progressively measurable** with respect to the filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_t\}$ if the mapping $(s, \omega) \mapsto X_s(\omega):([0, t] \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}([0, t])\otimes \mathcal{F_t}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ is measurable, for each $t \geq 0$.

The book I am following states that every progressively measurable process is measurable without further elaboration. This is not so obvious to me. When you specify that a process is measurable, it is always with respect to some sigma algebra. My sense is that the measurable space in mind here is $([0, \infty) \times \Omega, \mathcal{B}([0, \infty))\otimes \mathcal{F}_\infty)$ where $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma(\cup_{t \geq 0} \mathcal{F}_t)$. So my questions are two fold:

1. Is this the correct sigma algebra to consider for the implication (progressively measurable implies measurable)?
2. How would one go about proving such a statement?

For 2, $\mathcal{B}([0, t])$ is a filtration in its own right. So it is clear to me that $\mathcal{B}([0, t)) \subset \mathcal{B}([0, \infty))$ and $\mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{F}_\infty$. So all that's left to see is that $\mathcal{B}([0, t]) \otimes \mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \otimes \mathcal{F}_\infty$. Any $A \times B \in \mathcal{B}([0, t]) \times \mathcal{F}_t$ has $A \times B \in \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \times \mathcal{F}_\infty$, thus $A \times B \in \sigma(\mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \times \mathcal{F}_\infty) = \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \otimes \mathcal{F}_\infty$, hence $\mathcal{B}([0, t]) \times \mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \otimes \mathcal{F}_\infty$ and by minimality  $\mathcal{B}([0, t]) \otimes \mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{B}([0, \infty)) \otimes \mathcal{F}_\infty$. Is it really that simple, or am I missing something? The implication that progressively measurable implies adapted was easier for me to understand, since the sigma algebra there is clearly defined.

Comment: This is follows from the fact if $f:(X\times Y,\mathscr{X}\otimes\mathscr{Y})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable the for any $y\in Y$, $f^yX\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathscr{X}$-measurable; similarly, for any $x\in X$, the map $f_x:Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathscr{Y}$ measurable.